# $Y^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace of $X^*$

Tags: real-analysis

let $X$ be a Banach space and let $X^*$ be its dual space. Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of $X$.
I want to show that
$$Y^{\perp} = \{ x^* \in X^* : \langle y, x^* \rangle =0, \; \forall y \in Y \}$$
is a closed subspace of $X^*$.

Comment: What have you tried, and where exactly the problem is? Looks like it all follows directly from the definitions.

Comment: @Mark I'm new to topology and real analysis so I don't really know where to start from.

Comment: Write $Y^*=\bigcap_{y\in Y}(y^{**})^{-1}(\{0\})$. So, it is an intersection of the sets $(y^{**})^{-1}(\{0\})$, which are pre-images, by the continuous functions $y^{**}$, of the closed set $\{0\}$. Here $y^{**}(x^*)=\langle y,x^*\rangle$, for all $x^*\in X^*$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new, perhaps it is better to just mark out the steps and let you finish the details.

We say a set $A$ is closed(in a metric space) when for all sequences $x_{n}\in A$ which converges to a point $a\in X$, we have that $a\in A$.

So to show that $Y^{\perp}$ is closed, you take a sequence $y_{n}^{*}$ of elements of $Y^{\perp}$ such that $y_{n}^{*}\to y^{*}$ and $y^{*}\in X^{*}$.

Observe that for any $z\in Y$, you have $\langle y^{*}_{n},z\rangle =0$ for all $n$.

If $y_{n}\to y$, can you now conclude that $\langle y^{*},z\rangle =0$ by using limits

(Hint- $|\langle y^{*}_{n},z\rangle -\langle y^{*},z\rangle|\leq ||y^{*}_{n}-y^{*}||\cdot||z||$ and this holds for all $z\in Y$)

If you manage to do so, what can you tell about $y^{*}$? Does it not lie in $Y^{\perp}$?

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks